# OpenGL ES 3.0: writing to multiple buffers

Tags: opengl-es

One section of the OpenGL ES 3.0 spec is not completely clear to me.

https://www.khronos.org/registry/Ope...s_spec_3.0.pdf, page 185:

> If an OpenGL ES Shading Language 1.00 fragment shader writes to
>   gl_FragColor or gl_FragData, DrawBuffers specifies the draw buffer, if
>   any, into which the single fragment color defined by gl_FragColor or
>   gl_FragData[0] is written. If an OpenGL ES Shading Language 3.00
>   fragment shader writes a user-defined *varying out* variable,
>   DrawBuffers specifies a set of draw buffers into which each of the
>   multiple output colors defined by these variables are separately
>   written.

I understand this the following way:

1) If I use OpenGL ES 3.0 and write shaders using GLSL 1.0, then the only way I can write to 2 buffers at once (COLOR0 and COLOR1) is to manually specify what gets written to gl_FragData[0] and gl_FragData[1] in my fragment shader. If I then want to get back to writing only to COLOR0, I must switch glPrograms to one that only writes to gl_FragData[0] (or gl_FragColor).

2) If on the other hand I use OpenGL ES 3.0 and write my shaders using GLSL 3.0, then I can write a single fragment shader with output defined to be a single *varying out* variable, and dynamically switch on and off writing to COLOR1 with calls to DrawBuffers() and with no need to swap glPrograms.

Is the above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above correct?

No. In ESSL 1.0 shaders you can only write to a single color buffer `gl_FragData`, or it's alias `gl_FragData[0]`. There is no such thing as `gl_FragData[1]` in ESSL 1.0.

> and dynamically switch on and off writing to `COLOR1` with calls to `DrawBuffers()` and with no need to swap `glPrograms`.

Yes, this is how it works in ESSL 3.x.

However, in most cases it's far more efficient just to swap programs. You execute the shader program millions of times (once per fragment), so having one program containing all of the code for all color targets and just masking out output writes is horribly inefficient. Don't do it. You want you shader programs to be as close to optimal as possible - that's where your GPU runtime goes ...

Comment: Thanks. Still one question (which I guess I should just try doing instead of asking you): the spec seems to be saying that even with GLSL 1.0, I still can dynamically redirect output of gl_FragColor to any COLOR_ATTACHMENTi for any i for which there is something attached, all with a simple call to DrawBuffers()?

Comment: Never tried it to be honest; the only reason I've ever used MRT support is when I actually had multiple render targets; never tried to remap them.